# Make Redux return an array instead of nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So I'm trying to return an array with redux, with not much success until now.

I tried to log the action payload and until then, it seems okay, but when I actually update the state it returns a nested object instead of the array in the payload.

Meanwhile I modified the proptype to get an array but I get the error message of providing an object instead of an array so that's another problem.

Here is my reducer:

```js
import { GET_GROUPS_OF_USER } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    groups: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    console.log(action.payload);
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_GROUPS_OF_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                groups: action.payload
            };
            default:
                return state;
    }
}
```

The log says:

```
[{…}]
   0: {members: Array(1), _id: "5f69b4d9ba1b01fcc4736a85", name: "asd"}
   length: 1
   __proto__: Array(0)
```

So it seemed fine but its not.
The next thing I did was change the prop type to:

```js
Dashboard.propTypes = {
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    groups: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getGroupsOfUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

And here is my action for getting the groups:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { SERVER_ADDR } from '../config/keys';

import {
    GET_GROUPS_OF_USER,
    GET_ERRORS
} from './types';

export const getGroupsOfUser = data => dispatch => {
    axios.post(SERVER_ADDR + '/group/get', data).then(res => {
        console.log(typeof(res.data));
        dispatch({
            type: GET_GROUPS_OF_USER,
            payload: res.data
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data
        });
    }
    );
};
```

The result I'm getting in props is the following:

```
{auth: {…}, groups: {…}, getGroupsOfUser: ƒ}
auth: {isAuthenticated: true, user: {…}}
getGroupsOfUser: ƒ ()
groups:
    groups: [{…}]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

This is how I log out this.props after getting the results:

```js
    componentDidMount(){
        const data = {
            id: this.props.auth.user.id
        }
        this.props.getGroupsOfUser(data);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log(nextProps);
        if (nextProps.groups) {
            this.props = nextProps;
        }
    }
```

The log in the axios post result says the type of res.data is object, even though the server returns an array for sure.
I am probably doing a lot of things wrong besides that too, but this is what I can't figure out this time.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "even though the server returns an array for sure", just to ask a quick note, did you check network logs in browser just to be sure, so that we can go with alternative solutions

Comment: Yes I did. The response is an array.

Comment: In your question you say "The log says:" and the data looks just like array so where is the exact problem, am sorry I am unable to understand what you are trying to do, so may be a bit more explanation is needed for me to understand

Comment: The problem is, I can't make it so the returned properties look like groups: [ ],
now it returns groups: { groups: [ ] }, Edit: even though in the log, before updating the state, its still alright, but after the update, it becomes a nested object.

Comment: did you try making it `payload: res.data` to `payload: res.data.groups`, if not can you give it a try, and let me know what is the log in reducer now?

Comment: I did. It just becomes undefined, as res.data contains the array as it should, but it doesn't have a groups key inside. That is why I don't really understand why it returns the array inside a groups object, and not just set the value of groups to the array its returning.

Comment: From your question "The result I'm getting in props is the following:" below is the response object right? it has nested group... am expecting that to be data of `console.log(typeof(res.data));`

Comment: That's right. That's what I'm trying to change so it becomes groups: [ ] 
The problem I think is with the reducer's return, but I have no idea how to modify that so I get the right format. Edit: Inside the reducer, action.payload is still an array, the update messes it up somehow.

Comment: try spreading the `action.payload` like `[...action.payload]`, in reducer hope that works

Comment: I tried, but for some reason nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution. I had to modify the reducer return value to return action.payload and not { ...state, groups: action.payload }
The reducer code has now become:

```
import { GET_GROUPS_OF_USER } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = [], action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_GROUPS_OF_USER:
            return action.payload;   
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```